# i am trying to execute a r script from asp.net page using c# but it's not executing

Tags: c#, asp.net, r

I have used Rscript runner but its not working.

```
public static string SetupPath(string Rversion = "R-3.2.3")
        {
            var oldPath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
            var rPath = System.Environment.Is64BitProcess ?
            string.Format(@"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\bin\x64", Rversion) :
            string.Format(@"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\bin\i386", Rversion);

            if (!Directory.Exists(rPath))
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                  string.Format(" R.dll not found in : {0}", rPath));
            var newPath = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", rPath,
                                         System.IO.Path.PathSeparator, oldPath);
            System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", newPath);
            return newPath.ToString() ;
        }
```

This Button1_Click method calls the rscript runner.

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string s = SetupPath();
                string args = "";
                string r = @"D:\scr1.r";
                var RcodeFilePath = string.Format(@"D:\scr1.r", "R-3.2.3");

                //string c = RScriptRunner.RunFromCmd(RcodeFilePath, s);
                string c = RScriptRunner.RunFromCmd(r, "rscript.exe");
                Label1.Text = c;
            }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: NO error or exception is comming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution..!

I used "Shiny" a library in R.
This converts the r script into an app which can then be called from asp.net using simple http request.